# <img> not working with the url but when I put the url in browser it works

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

The following image shows as a broken image but when I put the URL in my browser it works fine.  After I access the image through my browser VIA url,  the image is cached and the image tag starts to work but once I clear my cache the image is broken again.  Can someone help me with this issue?

```
<img src="http://www.rktteam.vastserve.com/Brawlhalla-660x330.png" style="background-color: initial;">
```

[image]
I don't think its the HTTPS/HTTP mismatch issue.  On the left is a broken image with HTTP URL (it works when you access it in your browser).  On the right is another image with HTTP but it works even after I clear my cache.

See the full html here.
https://www.rkt-team.com/events/32

Comment: Is this image hosted on the same domain as the page?

Comment: This could be a related javascript issue.. I have no clue why the image is breaking.

Comment: The image is not on the same domain but that shouldn't be the issue right? I believe you can pull a image via url ?

Comment: The URL appears to be of an image, however actually redirects to a HTML page (which I can't see, as my Javascript and Cookie settings prevent even getting close to loading it). Aside from that, you're probably dealing with a server-side hotlink protection as it's commonly done via .htaccess files, to prevent people from accessing images from other servers.

Comment: www.rktteam.vastserve.com  is a seperate domain than www.rkt-team.   It has its own htaccess file but the that file it just an empty file.  Is there something I need to set in the htaccess file to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the browser requests the image, what the server returns is not an image at all - the MIME type is returned as text/html.

[image: Content Type: text/html]

Investigate the server if you want to find out why it's doing it.

Comment: I changed my website protocol to HTTP to match with the images but I'm still getting a issue.  I don't believe it is the HTTP/HTTPS protocol mismatch because I tried to put the following image on my website http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg  and it works fine.   It might be something to do with the protection you mentioned earlier but how do I fix this?  Is there something I can put in the htaccess file to bypass this protection?

Comment: @user2962698 I think you already did, the image does show up on your website for me...

Comment: Please take a look at the images in the OP

Comment: @user2962698 I don't know what images are these but the `img` tag you quoted is for the image which now shows up at the bottom of the page: http://www.rktteam.vastserve.com/Brawlhalla-660x330.png

Comment: Could you try to clear your cache and see if it is still showing?

Comment: @user2962698 No it's not

Comment: Do you have idea ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: I removed the part about hotlinking because I don't think now that's what's happening. In Firefox when I right clicked the entry for the image in Network tab I got redirected to something which was HTML page with this image in it: see screenshot http://imgur.com/3r44apE. This page then tried to redirect me to the image itself but McAffee blocked it. There was a strange part in the URL which I googled and here somebody says it's a bot detection feature: https://clicky.com/forums/?id=18265. Sorry, from now on you are on your own, you need to sort out your weird hosting.

Answer (score 3):

You link to a site using the `https` protocol, but the img you've referenced uses the `http` protocol. Due to security reasons you must not load unsecure (http) content, in an https site.

Change `http` to `https` or the other way round.

Comment: While it's something that should definitely be fixed, it would only generate a warning (at least in Chrome), as images are considered 'passive mixed content'. So it's not the only cause of OP's issue.

Comment: I changed my website to http but I still got the same issue.

Comment: True, the 2nd problem is probably the contentType (http header). Edit @kamilk it actually depends on the users settings in the browser, whether passive mixed content is shown.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with your output buffer. Is it built using php? Have you tried ob_clean()?

Comment: No it isn't built using php.   The website is on a python backend

Comment: I only ask because I know that ob_clean() is an easy way to clean the Output buffer in PHP. It could still be a problem with the output buffer, although I wouldn't know how to help with that in python.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to fix this.  The problem had to do with http://www.uhostall.com/.  However I was able to do a work around.  I changed my host to 000webhost and I am no longer getting this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove background-color